# VS Code: Can you set allowed encodings for "guess encoding"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

All my files are either UTF8 or Windows-1252, but VS Code incorrectly assumes some Greek encoding on files repeatedly.

Can you set up a list of allowed encodings so I can only add the above 2 to it somehow?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I guess the comment session may not be the right place to ask for it, but here I go: @MiK, have you found a solution? If so, could you post an Answer? Regards!

Comment: There is a feature request open on VScodes github, but we've all been waiting for quite some time for that feature by now, and there's no unity on how to implement it, or rather, the devs don't understand which implementation people want, when the overall tone seems to be for adding a list of possible encoding guesses...

Comment: I have found the issue on github as well and commented on it. I will try to create an extension that does the trick; at least one that solves the problem the way I think it should be solved. If I succeed I will coment here.